# Sending non-xml content in output stream

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How to send non xml (for example plain text) content in xquery codes in marklogic server?

I have seen that whatever we write, the output should always be xml format.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the xdmp:set-response-content-type function , e.g. `xdmp:set-response-content-type("text/plain")`, see the official [doc](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp%3aset-response-content-type)

Answer (score 1):

XQuery module output can be XML, or text, or binary, or any combination of those three. Here is a valid main module, yielding text (technically a string item, but if I needed a text node I could wrap it with the `text` constructor):

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
"hello world"
```

This module yields binary data:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
binary { xs:hexBinary("deadbeef") }
```

A module can also yield a sequence:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
"hello", "world"
```